# Why my asp-page taghelepr not working? Tag helper confusion ?:

Tags: .net

I have this issue.

```
<a asp-page="/AddProduct">BB</a>
<a asp-page="/EditProduct?Id=8">B</a>
```

asp-page working for the add product, but not working for the edit product.

Both pages in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

I fexed it by this anybody can explain the diffrence

```
 <a asp-page="/AddProduct">BB</a>
    <a asp-route-id="8" asp-page="/EditProduct">B</a>
```